# Request Web API for GET method

Tags: java, rest, get, parse-platform

I am working on a java module with Parse API. Recently I have to implement a request routine with `GET` method. So, I read a official Parse sample first and it's like below.

```
curl -X GET \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: MY-APP-ID" \
-H "X-Parse-Master-Key: MY-MASTER-KEY" \
-G \
--data-urlencode 'where={"memberId":"JAEG"}' \
--data-urlencode 'keys=objectId' \
https://api.parse.com/1/installations
```

I tested it on a terminal window and works well. But I need a Java code. I found several `GET` samples from Internet, but I realy don't understand how do I convert the `-G --data-urlencode ...` part into a Java code. I already wrote some `POST` routines and their's working perfectly. But the `GET` one failed everytime. I'm almost new to Java. Would you show me how to do it?

By the way, my working-good `POST` routine is like below. And I think the `GET` routine may use same classes and methods.

```
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-Application-Id", appId);
connection.setRequestProperty("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", restKey);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
String content = "{\"where\": {},\"data\": {\"alert\": \"Hello\",\"sound\": \"default\"}}";
OutputStreamWriter w = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
w.write(content);
w.close();
int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode(); // 200 = OK
```

Answer (score 1):

As the [man page for the cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-G) says,

> -G, --get
>
> When used, this option will make all data specified with -d, --data,
>   --data-binary or --data-urlencode to be used in an HTTP GET request instead of the POST request that otherwise would be used. The data
>   will be appended to the URL with a '?' separator.

The final URL of the GET request in your cURL example will become

https://api.parse.com/1/installations?where=%7B%22memberId%22%3A%22JAEG%22%7D&keys=objectId

In order to do the same with your java code,

```
    String urlBase = "https://api.parse.com/1/installations";
    String whereValue = "{\"memberId\":\"JAEG\"}";
    String keysValue = "objectId";
    String query = String.format("where=%s&keys=%s",
            URLEncoder.encode(whereValue, "UTF-8"),
            URLEncoder.encode(keysValue, "UTF-8"));
    URL url = new URL(urlBase + "?" + query);
```

You can then use a similar code to do a get request as you do in the POST. However, I would recommend using the [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.4.x/quickstart.html) which will make your life a bit easier instead of directly using the HttpsURLConnection class.

Comment: Thank you! Anyway, the project I'm working on uses older HttpClient library so that I had to down grade my original source codes. That's not good for me :(